# Pairing ifelse with dplyr in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

In the dataframe `df`, I want to assign a condition such that for a given month and level, if value is 0 or 1 then assign "alone". If not assign "together". In the end, I want to retain the original dataset rows but only add the assign column which will have repeated values. Here is my attempt, the error and needed outcome:

```
df <- data.frame(level = rep(c("1","2","3"), each = 5),
month = rep(c("J","J","A"), each = 5),
val = c(0,0,1,1,0,2,1,1,1,1,4,6,1,0,1))

df <- df %>%
      dplyr::mutate(level, month, count)%>%
      dplyr::group_by(month, level) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(assign = ifelse(df$val %in% c(0,1), "alone", "together"))

Error:
```

> Error in `mutate_cols()`: ! Problem with `mutate()` input `..3`. ℹ
> `..3 = count`. ✖ `..3` must be a vector, not a function.

Expected outcome

```
    level month val  assign

1      1     J   0  alone
2      1     J   0  alone
3      1     J   1  alone
4      1     J   1  alone
5      1     J   0  alone
6      2     J   2  together
7      2     J   1  together
8      2     J   1  together
9      2     J   1  together
10     2     J   1  together
11     3     A   4  together
12     3     A   6  together
13     3     A   1  together
14     3     A   0  together
15     3     A   1  together
```

Comment: (1) Typo, you define `val` but reference `count`, which is referring to `dplyr::count` (a *function*). (2) (Almost) Never use `df$` inside of a dplyr `mutate` or `summarize`, just use `ifelse(val %in% c(0,1), ...)`.

Comment: When I replace `count` with `val` and `df$val` with `val`, it works without error.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't get you wrong, maybe you can try with the following :

```
data.frame(level = rep(c("1","2","3"), each = 5),
           month = rep(c("J","J","A"), each = 5),
           val = c(0,0,1,1,0,2,1,1,1,1,4,6,1,0,1)) %>% 
        mutate(assign = ifelse(level == 0 | month == 0 | level == 1 | month == 1,
                      yes = "alone", no = "together"))
```

which will give you the following output :

```
   level month val   assign
1      1     J   0    alone
2      1     J   0    alone
3      1     J   1    alone
4      1     J   1    alone
5      1     J   0    alone
6      2     J   2 together
7      2     J   1 together
8      2     J   1 together
9      2     J   1 together
10     2     J   1 together
11     3     A   4 together
12     3     A   6 together
13     3     A   1 together
14     3     A   0 together
15     3     A   1 together
```

If that was not what you were specting, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

To return the original dataframe with the new column, you want to use `mutate` instead of `summarise`. Here, we can use `all` in the `ifelse` statement to limit to only those specific values in order to assign `alone`. You also don't need the first `mutate` statement in your code. Perhaps, you were wanting to use `select` from you original dataframe.

```
df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(month, level) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(assign = ifelse(all(val %in% c(0, 1)), "alone", "together"))
```

**Output**

```
   level month   val assign  
   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>   
 1 1     J         0 alone   
 2 1     J         0 alone   
 3 1     J         1 alone   
 4 1     J         1 alone   
 5 1     J         0 alone   
 6 2     J         2 together
 7 2     J         1 together
 8 2     J         1 together
 9 2     J         1 together
10 2     J         1 together
11 3     A         4 together
12 3     A         6 together
13 3     A         1 together
14 3     A         0 together
15 3     A         1 together
```